# maze solver with direction indicated

Tags: c++, recursion, maze

I want to show the directions of the path with symbols ">", "<", "v", "^". Yet symbols stop showing right at the first turning point. What's wrong with my code?

```
bool find_path_with_direction(int row, int col, char maze[ROW][COL])

{
     if(row > ROW-1 || col > COL-1)    //out of boundary
         return false;

    if(maze[row][col]=='d')   // destination
    return true;

    if(maze[row][col]!= ' '&& maze[row][col]!= 's')  //obstacle
    return false;


    if(find_path_with_direction(row, col+1, maze)==true)
    maze[row][col]= '>';
    return true;

    if(find_path_with_direction(row, col-1, maze)==true)
    maze[row][col]= '<';
    return true;

    if(find_path_with_direction(row+1, col, maze)==true)
    maze[row][col]= 'v';
    return true;

    if(find_path_with_direction(row-1, col, maze)==true)
    maze[row][col]= '^';
    return true;

    maze[row][col]=' ';

    return false;
}
```

Comment: you need to use `{` `}` `if(condition) { //code }`

Comment: @Himanshu You can omit them when there is only one line in the if, like in the first three conditions, yet you are right about the others.

Comment: @Kotshi, yes for single line it will be fine but for multiple statements you must have to use parenthesis.

Comment: @Himanshu That's what I meant by "you are right about the others.", maybe I wasn't clear enough? English isn't my first language.

Comment: @Kotshi, no problem, I got your point :)

Answer (score 2):

you are having problem in your if condition.

You are not using `{` and `}` which is giving problem.

Use opening and closing parenthesis `{` `}`
for example write your `if` condition like this.

```
if(find_path_with_direction(row, col+1, maze)==true)
{
    maze[row][col]= '>';
    return true;
}
```

if you are writing code like this.

```
if(find_path_with_direction(row, col+1, maze)==true)
maze[row][col]= '>';
return true;
```

Here, no matter condition is `true` or `false`, `return true;` will always be executed.

Comment: You pointed a bug OP was about to face but he said the problem comes from: `if(maze[row][col]!= ' '&& maze[row][col]!= 's')  //obstacle
    return false;`